# Set-Cookie blocked because Domain

Tags: cookies, setcookie

My API and my frontend are hosted on `render.com` but at different subdomains. When I log in, my API send a cookie with `SameSite=None`, `Secure=true` and frontend domain. But Chrome refused to set the cookie and block it. How to handle this situation? What I am missing?

[image]